# Can I control the XML element names for an array and its items as the return value from an asynchronous .Net ASMX web method?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, asynchronous, asmx

Consider the following .Net ASMX web service with two web methods.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace DemoWebService
{
 public class
 ArrayItem
 {
  public int
  Value1;

  public int
  Value2;
 };

 [WebService(Namespace = "http://begen.name/xml/namespace/2009/09/demo-web-service/")]
 [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
 public class DemoService :
  WebService
 {
  [WebMethod]
  [return: XmlArray("Items")]
  [return: XmlArrayItem("Item")]
  public ArrayItem []
  GetArray()
  {
   return BuildArray();
  }

  [WebMethod]
  public IAsyncResult
  BeginGetArrayAsync(AsyncCallback callback, object callbackData)
  {
   BuildArrayDelegate fn = BuildArray;
   return fn.BeginInvoke(callback, callbackData);
  }

  [WebMethod]
  [return: XmlArray("Items")]
  [return: XmlArrayItem("Item")]
  public ArrayItem []
  EndGetArrayAsync(IAsyncResult result)
  {
   BuildArrayDelegate fn = (BuildArrayDelegate)((AsyncResult)result).AsyncDelegate;
   return fn.EndInvoke(result);
  }

  private delegate ArrayItem []
  BuildArrayDelegate();

  private ArrayItem []
  BuildArray()
  {
   ArrayItem [] retval = new ArrayItem[2];
   retval[0] = new ArrayItem();
   retval[0].Value1 = 1;
   retval[0].Value2 = 2;
   retval[1] = new ArrayItem();
   retval[1].Value1 = 3;
   retval[1].Value2 = 4;

   return retval;
  }
 }
}
```

The GetArray and GetArrayAsync web methods both return an array of `ArrayItem`s. The GetArrayAsync web method, however, is implemented using the asynchronous programming model.

Through the use of the [XmlArray] and [XmlArrayItem] attributes applied to the return value of the `GetArray()` method, I've been able to control the XML elements .Net uses to serialize the return value and get a result like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetArrayResponse xmlns="http://begen.name/xml/namespace/2009/09/demo-web-service/">
      <Items>
        <Item>
          <Value1>int</Value1>
          <Value2>int</Value2>
        </Item>
        <Item>
          <Value1>int</Value1>
          <Value2>int</Value2>
        </Item>
      </Items>
    </GetArrayResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Notice how the return value has the XML element name of "Items" and each item in the array has the XML element name of "Item".

I have applied the same attributes to the `EndGetArrayAsync()` method, but they don't seem to affect the response the way they do for the synchronous `GetArray()` method. In this case the response looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetArrayAsyncResponse xmlns="http://begen.name/xml/namespace/2009/09/demo-web-service/">
      <GetArrayAsyncResult>
        <ArrayItem>
          <Value1>int</Value1>
          <Value2>int</Value2>
        </ArrayItem>
        <ArrayItem>
          <Value1>int</Value1>
          <Value2>int</Value2>
        </ArrayItem>
      </GetArrayAsyncResult>
    </GetArrayAsyncResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

In this case, the return value was given the default XML element name of "GetArrayAsyncResult" and the array items have the XML element name coming from the C# class name, "ArrayItem".

Is there any way to get an asynchronous web method to respect the [XmlArray] and [XmlArrayItem] attributes applied to the return value of the End* method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this to be a bug in the .Net framework as the only difference between the two web methods in my example is that one is asynchronous and the two `[return: *]` attributes are placed on the `End*()` method of the asynchronous implementation.

I have found a work-around that makes the WSDL essentially identical for the synchronous and asynchronous versions of the web method, and thus makes the SOAP response use the XML element names I want for the array.

I need to change the `End*()` method to not have a return value and instead use an output parameter to return the array. The `[XmlArrayItem]` attribute is then placed on that parameter instead of the return value of the method. Here is the revised `EndGetArrayAsync()` method that does what I want.

```
    [WebMethod]
    public void
    EndGetArrayAsync(IAsyncResult result, [XmlArrayItem("Item")] out ArrayItem [] Items)
    {
        BuildArrayDelegate fn = (BuildArrayDelegate)((AsyncResult)result).AsyncDelegate;
        Items = fn.EndInvoke(result);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[See this question...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052556/how-do-i-add-a-attribute-to-a-xmlarray-element-xml-serialization)

You need to add the XmlType() attribute to the class used in the array and then specify only the XmlArray() attribute on the class member defining the array.

Comment: Putting an [XmlType("Item")] attribute on the class used in the array, ArrayItem in my example, does change the XML element name for the items in the array to "Item". Removing the [XmlArrayItem] attribute from the EndGetArrayAsync() method to leave only the [XmlArray] attribute did not, however, get the XML element name for the array to change; it was still the default <GetArrayAsyncResult>.

Also, I am specifically trying to avoid having to define the attributes at the ArrayItem class, preferring to have control at each web method.

Thank you for the suggestion, though.