# How to create xml from a template-c#

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have a xml template like this

```
<User>
<UserId></UserId>
<UserName></UserName>
<Roles>
<Role></Role>
<Roles></Role>
</Roles>
</User>
```

Form this xml template file,dynamicaly i want to generate an xml.How can i do this.

Output xml should look like this

```
<User>
<UserId>user1</UserId>
<UserName>fr</UserName>
<Roles>
<Role>abc</Role>
<Role>def</Role>
</Roles>
</User>
```

How can i achieve this.What all changes i need to make in template file.How to read and create xml from this tempalte xml file using c#.

Comment: Where's the data coming from that needs to go into the XML?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`XmlSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) and create a simple class with properties according to the template:

```
public class User
{
   public UserId{get;set;}

   ...
}
```

And serialize the class to XML file.

There's a good example [here](http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/csharp/xmlserializer-example.htm).

**Option #2**:
If for some reason you do not want to use `XmlSerializer` use `XmlWriter` - in order to prevent forgetting to close elements I suggest you use "AutoClose" XmlWriter - I've blogged about how to create this simple class on my blog - [XmlWriter that automatically close elements using IDisposable](http://blog.drorhelper.com/2009/07/xmlwriter-that-automatically-close.html)

Comment: i am not plannig to use xmlserializer

Comment: Why not? this way you only need to maintain code and do not need to write every single XML node "by hand"

Comment: Better answer than what i gave

Comment: i have list in which it contain three objects.I want to create an xml with all three object details,then how it will be?

Comment: There are several attributes you can use to change the way that take a look at this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292480/xmlserializer-list-item-element-name

Comment: [XmlWriter that automatically close elements using IDisposable](http://blog.drorhelper.com/2009/07/xmlwriter-that-automatically-close.html) has a pretty good implementation with c# using and .Net IDisposable. If you'd like XmlWriter, this is a good way to avoid all the WriteEnd... methods.

Comment: I do:) And I liked the way you of using the using. Seems pretty native c#.

Answer (score 6):

Serializing is an option, but if you really need a template, you can use this https://github.com/beto-rodriguez/Templator

here is an example

C#

```
UserClass user = new UserClass();
user.UserId = 1;
user.UserName = "my name";
User.Roles = new List<string>(){"admin", "sales"};
//some other properties...    

var compiler = new Compiler()
            .AddElementToScope("user", user);

var compiled = compiler.CompileXml(@"C:\...\myXml.xml")
```

XLM Source

```
<User>
  <UserId>{{user.UserId}}</UserId>
  <UserName>{{user.UserName}}</UserName>
  <Roles Tor.Repeat="role in user.Roles">
    <Role>{{role}}</Role>
  <Roles></Role>
  </Roles>
</User>
```

Compiled

```
<User>
  <UserId>1</UserId>
  <UserName>my name</UserName>
  <Roles>
    <Role>admin</Role>
    <Role>sales</Role>
  <Roles></Role>
  </Roles>
</User>
```

you can install it from Nuget too:

```
Install-Package SuperXML
```

Comment: can downvoter plase let me know why this is not an option?

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, so much more elegant with more complex templates than what you get with `XmlSerializer` and having to navigate a large document dotted with variables.

Answer (score 0):

Use XmlTextReader

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307548

[http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/ReadWriteXMLTutMellli2111282005041517AM/ ReadWriteXMLTutMellli21.aspx](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/ReadWriteXMLTutMellli2111282005041517AM/ReadWriteXMLTutMellli21.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
var templateXML = "C://template.xml"//full path for the template xml
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
FileStream fs = new FileStream(templateXML, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
doc.Load(fs);
XmlNode node = doc.DocumentElement;
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("pf", "http://www.example.com/abc");
node = doc.DocumentElement;
nodeName = "/pf:Message/pf:User/pf:UserID";
node.SelectSingleNode(nodeName, nsmgr).InnerXml = "user1";put you custom value
nodeName = "/pf:Message/pf:User/pf:UserName";                
node.SelectSingleNode(nodeName, nsmgr).InnerXml = "fr";put you custom value
....
.....
.......
var postData = node.ParentNode.InnerXml;
postData = node.OuterXml;
```