# How to check the values of attributes are in ascending order and also find duplicates?

Tags: c#, xml

Here is a sample xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
    <book id="bk101">
        <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
        <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
        <genre>Computer</genre>
        <price>44.95</price>
        <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
        <description>An in-depth look at creating applications
        with XML.</description>
    </book>
    <book id="bk102">
        <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
        <title>Midnight Rain</title>
        <genre>Fantasy</genre>
        <price>5.95</price>
        <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
        <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies,
            an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen
        of the world.</description>
    </book>
    <book id="bk102">
        <author>Corets, Eva</author>
        <title>Maeve Ascendant</title>
        <genre>Fantasy</genre>
        <price>5.95</price>
        <publish_date>2000-11-17</publish_date>
        <description>After the collapse of a nanotechnology
            society in England, the young survivors lay the
        foundation for a new society.</description>
    </book>
    <book id="bk103">
        <author>Corets, Eva</author>
        <title>Oberon's Legacy</title>
        <genre>Fantasy</genre>
        <price>5.95</price>
        <publish_date>2001-03-10</publish_date>
        <description>In post-apocalypse England, the mysterious
            agent known only as Oberon helps to create a new life
            for the inhabitants of London. Sequel to Maeve
        Ascendant.</description>
    </book>
</catalog>
```

How do I check whether or not the values of the attribute **id** in the nodes `<book>` are in ascending order, also find if there are duplicate values in it in the simplest possible way.
I did

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    XDocument myfile = XDocument.Parse(File.ReadAllText(@"D:\sample_xml.xml"));
    var check = myfile.Descendants("book").Select(a => a.Attribute("id").Value.Substring(2)).ToArray();

    if (IsSortedAscending(check))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sorted in Ascending order");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Check Sequence");
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}


public static bool IsSortedAscending(string[] arr)
{
    for (int i = arr.Length - 2; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (arr[i].CompareTo(arr[i + 1]) > 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

But it doesn't account for duplicate values...How do I do that?

Also, is it possible to find the missing value(if any) in the attribute **id**, e.x. if there is **bk109** and the next one is **bk112** then the program will show that **bk110** and **bk111** are missing.

Comment: use XML deserialization to load xml data on to objects and then use LINQ. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18340427/read-from-xml-file-into-c-sharp-class-using-serialization

Comment: @RudreshaParameshappa: Why bother deserialing? LINQ to XML makes this trivial.

Comment: @DaisyShipton oh yeah, thanks I forgot that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're nearly there already - the only difference between "strictly ascending, no duplicates" and "ascending, allowing duplicates" is what you do when the result of the comparison is 0 (i.e. the value is the same as the previous one).

You just need to change your `IsSortedAscending` method to return `false` if the result of the comparison is `>= 0` rather than just `> 0`:

```
public static bool IsSortedAscending(string[] arr)
{
    for (int i = arr.Length - 2; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        // Fail if this ID is equal to or bigger than the next one.
        if (arr[i].CompareTo(arr[i + 1]) >= 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

(You could also use `Skip` and `Zip` as an alternative way of comparing elements pairwise, but that's a slightly different matter.)

Note that currently your code may fail if your numbers are of different lengths. For example, consider IDs "bk99" and "bk100". That will compare "99" with "100" *as strings* and decide that "99" comes after "100".

If your IDs are always really "bk" followed by an integer, I would parse them early:

```
var ids = myfile.Descendants("book")
                .Select(a => a.Attribute("id").Value.Substring(2))
                .Select(id => int.Parse(id))
                .ToArray();
```

You'd then change your method to accept an `int[]` instead of a `string[]`.

At that point, it's much easier to check for "missing" IDs too - in string form, there's no real concept of a "missing" ID, as you could have "bk101", "bk101a", "bk101c" - is "bk101b" missing there? If so, what about "bk101aa"? With integers, it's much simpler.

Once you've got your array of integer IDs, you can use the length of the array to check whether any values are missing:

```
if (ids.Length > 0 ids.Length - 1 != ids.Last() - ids.First())
{
    Console.WriteLine("At least one ID is missing");
}
```

That won't tell you *which* ID is missing, admittedly.

Comment: but how do I check for missing values in the sequence

Comment: @TamalBanerjee: Ah, I'd missed that part. I'll edit - along with an aspect of numbers...

Comment: @TamalBanerjee: Have a look now.

Answer (score -1):

I would just sort elements and put into a dictionary :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            XElement catalog = doc.Root;

            Dictionary<string, List<XElement>> dict = catalog.Elements("book")
                .OrderBy(x => (string)x.Attribute("id"))
                .ThenBy(x => (DateTime)x.Element("publish_date"))
                .GroupBy(x => (string)x.Attribute("id"), y => y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.ToList());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why did you use "publish_date"? I only need to query the `book` nodes and nothing else

Comment: What are you calling a duplicate?  Usually with duplicates you want to take latest so I sorted.

Comment: I do not wish to update the file, I just want to check whether the values of `id` are in ascending order and whether there are any duplicate `id` values of the node `book`...