# How to serialize object to xml with circular dependency in c#?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I've got an object which has a circular dependency

```
    public class Levels
    {
        public UserDescription user { get; set; }
        public List<Levels> friends {get; set;}

        public Levels(UserDescription user, List<Levels> friends)
        {
           this.user = user;
           this.friends = friends;
        }

        public Levels() { }            
    }
```

I need to serialize it to xml, so I do the following:

```
    public string SerializeObject(object obj)
    {
        System.Xml.XmlDocument xmlDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
        using (System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
        {
            serializer.Serialize(ms, obj);
            ms.Position = 0;
            xmlDoc.Load(ms);
            return xmlDoc.InnerXml;
        }
    }
```

This code throws an exception System.InvalidOperationException on`serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer`. How can I solve this?

Comment: 1. Show exception details

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Circular Reference when using XML Serialization?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815182/circular-reference-when-using-xml-serialization)

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28044648/xmlserializer-system-invalidoperationexception

Comment: Compiles and runs without any problems for me... how do you create your top-level instance?

Comment: I create it like Levels levels = new Levels(masha.getDescription(), levelsList); levelsList is list of Levels

Comment: @HimBromBeere you are right, I've just corrected it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that class UserDescription didn't have an empty constructor.