# How to write List<int> items into an xml file?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, list, xelement

I need to write items in the `List<int> myList` into an xml file. The way the xml file should look like is if the values in the list are 1, 2 and 3. I know this is possible using linq. I want to avoid the serializer options.

```
<List>
  <itemValue>1</itemValue>
  <itemValue>2</itemValue>
  <itemValue>3</itemValue>
</List>
```

Comment: You can use the [XmlSerializerClass](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class. Read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292480/xmlserializer-list-item-element-name), it is a similar question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
private static void ToXml(List<int> list)
{
    var doc = new XDocument(new XElement("List", list.Select(x =>
                          new XElement("itemValue", x))));
    doc.Save("test.xml");
}
```