# Serialisation XML C# .net2.0

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I've this element in my class

```
[XmlArray("photos")]         
public List<zPhoto> EntityPhotos;
```

when I serialize my class I get this :

```
<photos>
    <zPhoto id="73102" type="a" />
    <zPhoto id="73102" type="b"/>
    <zPhoto id="73105" type="a" />
    <zPhoto id="73105" type="b" />
</photos>
```

In order to simplify xpath query I want to add a new directive that will give me a result like

```
<photos count="2" >
    <zPhoto id="73102" type="a" />
    <zPhoto id="73102" type="b"/>
    <zPhoto id="73105" type="a" />
    <zPhoto id="73105" type="b" />
</photos>
```

I want to add trival attributes name and set the value. is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the attribute above your member variable

```
 [XmlAttribute("count")]
```

**EDIT**

This has been covered in a previous question on SO

[How do I add a attribute to a XmlArray element (XML Serialization)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052556/how-do-i-add-a-attribute-to-a-xmlarray-element-xml-serialization)

Comment: Have you made the variable public?

Comment: If you still struggle check this page:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052556/how-do-i-add-a-attribute-to-a-xmlarray-element-xml-serialization

Comment: Ok it's good can you edit your answer to add the url Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to introduce a custom generic collection class that serializes itself the way you want.

Answer (score -2):

You can replace String type with you ZPhotos type.

```
[XmlRoot("EntityPhotos")]
    public class EntityPhotos
    {
        private List<String> _photos;

        public EntityPhotos()
        {
            _photos = new List<string>
            {
                "One.jpg",
                "Two.png",
                "Three.gif"
            };
        }

        [XmlElement("Photos")]
        public String[] Photos
        {
            get
            {
                return _photos.ToArray();
            }

            set  {;}

        }

        [XmlAttribute("Count")]
        public Int32 Count
        {
            get
            {
                if (Photos != null)
                    return Photos.Length;
                else
                    return 0;
            }

            set{;}
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand why you tell me to replace with a string, In my answer I take photo but it could be other thing.

Comment: Instead of using String[] Photos, you could replace it with ZPhoto[] Photos as you wanted ZPhoto  to serialize.

Comment: OK I understand can you edit your answer cause I can't dismiss my vote down