# .NET XML Serializer - Array Custom Attributes

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization

I'm totally stumped as to how can I achieve XML structure such as this:

```
<sizes type=”1”>
    <size status=”1”>L</size>
    <size status=”1”>XL</size>
   <size status=”0”>XXL</size>
<sizes>
```

I am able to create such structure:

```
<sizes>
    <size>L</size>
    <size>XL</size>
   <size>XXL</size>
<sizes>
```

With `XmlArray` and `XmlArrayItem` attributes.

```
[XmlArray(ElementName = "sizes")]
[XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "size")]
```

But what I'm unable to do is to add those custom attributes. How do I go about doing that? Do I have to create a new object that'll hold those values and set a custom attribute for it?

Comment: Duplicate Post : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052556/how-do-i-add-a-attribute-to-a-xmlarray-element-xml-serialization][1]

Answer (score 1):

You should define them as attributes. This should work:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

public class sizes
{
    [XmlAttribute("type")]
    public string type { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("size")]
    public List<size> sizeList { get; set; }
}

public class size
{
    [XmlAttribute("status")]
    public string status { get; set; }
}
```

and the code to deserialize:

```
string xml = File.ReadAllText("XMLFile1.xml");
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(sizes));
var sizes = ser.Deserialize(new StringReader(xml));
```